# Multiple conditions on a temporary table - MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a temporary table called 'tempaction'. I wanted to select rows where 'ActionID' matches that of another table. I got the safe update mode error, I think as ActionID is part of a compound primary key. However, when I try

```
UPDATE action
SET Status = 'Sent'
WHERE ActionID IN( select ActionID from tempaction)
AND DeviceID IN( select DeviceID from tempaction);
```

I get temporary table cannot be reopened error.

Checking both parts of primary key has worked for the safe update error in the past. I also understand that I cannot reference a temporary table twice in the same statement.

How can I select rows with matching ActionID's or matching ActionID's AND DeviceID's from this temporary table?

Tempory Table

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempaction (ActionID BIGINT)
SELECT * 
FROM action
WHERE DeviceID = '1234'
AND Status = 'Pending'
```

Comment: can you please share details of your work

Answer (score 0):

You can try Update using Join with sub-query.

```
UPDATE action a
JOIN
    tempaction t ON a.ActionID = t.ActionID 
SET 
    a.Status = 'Sent';
```